# "\verb" does not work within a footnote for special characters such as _ or #

Tags: symbols

For example

```
\footnote{\verb+https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_France+}
```

treats `_` as meaning a subscript and produces `o` as a subscript of `n` and `F` as a subscript of `f`.

Comment: yes. that is known. Use the url package and its \urldef command instead.

Answer (score 2):

As a general answer the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report`, `article`) has a `\verbfootnote` macro which lets you include verbatin material in a footnote.

```
% verbfprob.tex  SE 564552
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
Some text%
\verbfootnote{Footnote with a \verb!verbatim entry! as shown}
followed by more text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\verb` does not work in the arguments to any command. The simplest approach is to use `\texttt` and explicitly escape special characters, e.g.,

```
\footnote{\texttt{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution\_of\_France}}
```

although there isn't a simple escape for a backslash so maybe not so simple as you desire.

I have to admit I'm not crazy about the `memoir` class solution. It feels to me that `memoir` includes a lot of functionality that really should be in packages rather than the document class.

For URLs, there is the `url` package as mentioned by Ulrike Fischer in the comment on your question. This has the advantage that it incorporates line breaking in a fashion that we would expect for URLs while `\verb` and the `\texttt` solution above do not. To do this, you would, somewhere before your footnote do something along the lines of

```
\urldef{\frenchconst}\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_France}
```

and then in your footnote you could write

```
\footnote{\frenchconst}
```

Comment: You say that "`\verb` does not work in the arguments to any command" but the `memoir` class, which you dislike, disproves that. Also Knuth's `footnote` macro can include `\verb` text in its argument. One of the ideas behind `memoir` was to reduce the number of packages for most documents.

Comment: The separation of concerns between classes and packages was intentional. There are a lot of bad classes (and packages) on CTAN. imho. A well-designed document (and document class) would require changing absolutely nothing before `\begin{document}` to change classes. `memoir` bundles a lot of stuff that would be better unbundled.

`\verbfootnote` does not actually allow `\verb` in an argument, it uses `\aftergroup` trickery to make it look like it does.